# Best approach to retrieve ordered counter from Cassandra

Tags: python, database, database-design, cassandra

I'm using Cassandra to save word and its frequency.

The table schema will be like

```
CREATE TABLE keywords_rate (
    some_id int,
    keyword Text,
    frequency counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (some_id, keyword)
);
```

The problem is, I have millions of records and I need to get the top 100 keywords for each `some_id`

but to do this, I need to get all keywords for given `some_id` and sort them on the backend (python), then get the first 100 records. which is a very costly operation for me.

So my question is: can I sort the counter inside Cassandra? and if not, what is the best approach to this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Cassandra for just this use case, and if you don't have a lot of investment on it already, my best advice is... Choose a different database. :) Cassandra was not designed for this.

If you NEED to use Cassandra, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147031/824644) that's based on how eBay organizes their data.

But again, if you have the option, use another technology for this use case. This will be very messy in Cassandra.